# $v_{p}(n):=e$ if $p^{e}|n$ and $p^{e+1} \nmid n$. Show that $v_{p}(n*m)= v_{p}(n)+ v_{p}(m)$ and $v_{p}(n+m)=v_{p}(n)$ or $v_{p}(n+m)\geq v_{p}(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Happy new year. This seems like an easy to solve task but I'm stuck right now, so any help is appreciated.

Let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a prime number. The function $v_{p}(n)\geq 0$ is defined as $v_{p}(n):=e$ if $p^{e}|n$ and $p^{e+1} \nmid n$. $v_{p}(0):=\infty$ and $\infty + e = e + \infty = \infty$ for all $e\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Show that i) $v_{p}(n*m)= v_{p}(n)+ v_{p}(m)$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

ii)$v_{p}(n+m)=v_{p}(n)$ if $v_{p}(n)<v_{p}(m)$ and $v_{p}(n+m)\geq v_{p}(n)$ if $v_{p}(n)=v_{p}(m)$.

I would also like to know if this function has a specific name so that I can find more about it and read it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: One of its names is "$p$-adic valuation". Regarding the proofs - what's the difficulty you see?

Comment: Indeed, which parts of the instantly accepted answer below was representing the least difficulty to you?

Comment: I'm usually having troubles to find the right way to start. I could find the proper way to define $n$ and $m$ with the name of the function and was editing my post with a solution when the answer showed up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). I will write $v(n) = v_p(n)$ for the remainder of the answer.

Let $n,m \in \Bbb{Z}$ and write $n = p^{v(n)}a$, $m = p^{v(m)}b$ with $a,b$ coprime to $p$. Then $$nm = p^{v(m)+v(n)}ab$$ and $ab$ is coprime to $p$ so $v(nm) = v(n) + v(m)$. This proves $(i)$. For $(ii)$, without loss of generality suppose that $v(n) \leq v(m)$. Then $$n + m = p^{v(n)}(a + p^{v(n)-v(m)}b)$$ If $v(n) > v(m)$ then $p \nmid a + p^{v(n)-v(m)}b$ and hence $v(n+m) = v(n)$. If $v(n) = v(m)$ then $v(n+m) = v(n) + v(a + b)$ - in particular, since $v(a + b) \geq 0$, $v(n+m) \geq v(n)$.

Note that your $(ii)$ is often more succinctly written as $v(n + m) \geq \min(v(n),v(m))$ with equality if $v(n) \neq v(m)$. Another thing to note is that $v_p$ can be uniquely extended to $\Bbb{Q}$ be $v_p(\frac{a}{b}) = v_p(a) - v_p(b)$.

---

As a final thing, the notion of a [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)) on a field (or ring) generalises the notion of the $p$-adic valuation. If $K$ is a field, then a valuation $v$ on $K$ is a function $v : K \rightarrow \Bbb{R} \cup \infty$ satisfying:

- $v(x) = \infty$ if and only if $x = 0$
- $v(xy) = v(x) + v(y)$ for all $x,y \in K$
- $v(x + y) \geq \min(v(x),v(y))$ for all $x,y \in K$ with equality if and only if $v(x) \neq v(y)$

So in fact all we have done is defined a function using the two properties that you've been asked to prove for the $p$-adic valuation. These valuations are incredibly powerful tools which are studied and used extensively in modern number theory.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I found the right way to define $n$ and $m$ with metamorphy's answer and was editing my post with a semi solution when your answer showed up.